# How to deal with difference in server and local time when using JWTs?

Tags: php, c++, jwt

### Introduction

Hello, right now I have a program (written in C++) that uses JWT with `exp` and `nbf`.

My server uses UTC and my clients use a lot of different timezones and some of them have the wrong hour/minutes set on their system.

On my php API I'm using `time()` and on the c++ app I'm using `GetSystemTimeAsFileTime`.

### The problem

To give a simple and realistic example, one of my users had the wrong hour set and the jwt was not valid because it was already expired according to his time.

### Things I tried

I thought, well, I can ask the server for his time so the user's time won't affect the program. But there is a flaw, if the jwt contains the time and that value is used to compare with `nbt` or `exp` then it will be always valid.

Is asking the user to set the correct time the only way to fix this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why should the server care what the client's time is for JWT? The server checks its own time for `exp` and `nbf`. It doesn't trust the user to report it. Do you clients not have the incorrect time because they're not using NTP? Most modern operating systems that I know of (not an expert on this though) certainly can calculate UTC if they don't already store their clocks in it to begin with. Are your clients' applications discarding tokens because they think they're no longer good?

Comment: What is your app developed on? What OS? Getting UTC time will be different depending on the OS.

Comment: Tangential, but this is in the intro of the RFC: "The suggested pronunciation of JWT is the same as the English word "jot"." It's obviously a w, so jwt --> juut --> "jooooot"

Comment: Hello, the OS is Windows in this case the users use w7, w8, w8.1 and w10. As said the app is written on C++. The client checks the `nbf`` and `exp` to see if the jwt is valid. Should I tell the users that they have to fix their datetime? or is this a bad way to fix this problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your problem is "one of my users had the wrong hour". The solution is "make sure all your clients  have the right hour". The timestamp has nothing to do with the timezones or the OS. It should be the same for all computers and servers if correctly synchronized with NTP

Comment: @Carlos all users should have the correct datetime. That doesn't mean they need to switch their timezone to UTC - that just means the client application needs to find out what the current UTC time is. The RFC for JWT suggests the server to give some leeway when checking `exp` and `nbf`. My suggestion would be for the client to give even more than that, and have the server tell them the JWT is expired.

Comment: So it is user's fault then. Thank you for your help